siremis configuretion on php8.3
I want to configure siremis on php version 8.3 and use it, is it possible?  If so, how should I do it?
I used php version 7.3 and there was no problem, but after using php version 8.3 I lost the localhost configuration page and could not configure Siremis properly.

As of today, Siremis has no support for PHP 8.x.
